# How to replace index/match with a connection

Tags: excel

In order to view customer data in an Excel sheet I have used the functions index/match to retrieve data. However, due to the large amount of customers the file has gotten very large. Right now it is 13MB. This file is regularly sent through mail, so it is a real headache having to open it every time.

Is there a way to replace Index/Match with something else in order to reduce the file size? Transforming the source file into an SQL file? Adding a connection to the source file?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I can use any add-ins, because the file is used by multiple people and it is practically impossible to install it on all systems. Is there any VBA code that can efficiently replace index/match?

Comment: if the workbook is on a network drive or something you can query it using ADO instead like a database using SQL

Comment: Did you save it as an XLSB?

Comment: @MacroMan Thanks. I'm gonna give adodb a try. I didn't know something like this existed.

Comment: @Jeeped No? Is that a smaller than xlsm?

Comment: @MacroMan Great suggestion. It works! I reduced the file size from 13MB to 2MB.